# Error when checking model input: Expected to see 290 array(s), but instead got the following list of 1 arrays

Tags: python, tensorflow, input, keras

Im trying to train a NN with 290 input arrays. In order to achieve that, I created the input in this way:

```
inputs = []
for i in range(0,288):
    inputs.append(Input(shape=(6,), name='input'+str(i)))

efic_ener = Input(shape=(1,))
poten_instal = Input(shape=(1,))
inputs.append(efic_ener)
inputs.append(poten_instal)
```

So finally I have a list of 290 arrays.
Input data has been preprocessed in order to get that dimensionality, but it is inside a list, so when Im trying to train the NN, i get the error:

```
Error when checking model input: the list of Numpy arrays that you are passing to your model is not the size the model expected. Expected to see 290 array(s), but instead got the following list of 1 arrays:
```

Due to the fact that is data is inside a list. Do you know a way to overcome this problem? Ty

PS: I have seen that I can create those 290 arrays one-by-one, by Im trying to skip that :P

Comment: what is your actual input shape?I mean why you are appending a shape `(6,)` like this? post your first 5 sample of input datastet

Comment: Hi shubham. I need a dense connection every 6 array positions, but they must be isolated from other dense connections, but an example of 5 first elements would be [[1,1,1,1,1,1],[1,1,1,1,1,1],[1,1,1,1,1,1],[1,1,1,1,1,1],[1,1,1,1,1,1]...]

Comment: And every 1 that I have writeen, is a list, obviously

Comment: that's mean you have shape of `(290,6)` ? why don't you just  do `inp=Input(shape=(6,))` one time before feeding into the dense layer as `x = Dense(10)(inp)`

Comment: Not really. In fact its a 3-D array: I have 3000 rows, where each row has 290 elements (that would be the input layer), but these 290 elements must be grouped (and isolated) every 6 elements. Thats the reason why Im creating a "list of Inputs"